# R-Tree implementation in Java

Tags: java, r-tree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R-Tree Implementation Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456240/r-tree-implementation-java)

Are there any r-tree implementations in Java that can support an arbitrary number of dimensions?

I have only found java r-tree implementations for 2D data.

Comment: Does this link help? https://www.google.com/search?q=r-tree+implementation+in+Java+that+can+support+an+arbitrary+number+of+dimensions

Comment: Actually all the good r-tree implementations I've seen support more than 2 dimensions... you need to search more.

Comment: This implementation might be what you are looking for:  https://github.com/davidmoten/rtree